# Is the following statement correct or incorrect?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the following statement is true or False ?

let G be a finite group with a normal subgroup H such that $\frac{G}{H}$ has order $7$. then $G\cong H \times \frac {G}{H}$

im thinking that the statement will be true because if i take $G= Z_{14}$ and$ H= Z_7$ now $ Z_{14} =Z_7 \times Z_2$

which is satisfied the above statement . so from my point of view  this statment is true ..

Is its corrects ?...........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: When is $\Bbb Z_{mn}$ not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_m\times \Bbb Z_n$?

Comment: when gcd(m,n)$ \neq1$ but here  question is about normal subroup ...

Comment: @Stupid When the group is abelian, all subgroups are normal. Also, $\Bbb Z_m$ is (isomorphic to) a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_{mn}$, namely $\langle n\rangle$.

Comment: thanks arthur sir